# Authorizing Google API on Headless Machine in Python

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Running Linux (ubuntu and python in docker on Raspberry OS) on a headless Raspberry Pi 4.

Followed [Google's Python Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) and got it to the point where it asks me to go to a URL like this:

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A59875%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&state=xxxxx&access_type=offline
```

Because I am headless and on SSH, I copied to my GUI computer and sign in authorize, but I get a request back to `localhost:59875/?state=xxxxx&code=xxxxx&scope=xxxx` which obviously does not open as nothing on my local machine is listening. I see that redirect URI in the above link with `localhost`, but changing that is invalid per [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation).

**How can I authorize Google API on a headless machine?**

Short of creating a webpage on my pi and using that to run the python (which is more than I want to do right now, especially not knowing if it will work), how can I do this?

**EDIT**
I am creating a python program that will interact with Google Calendar. I have a developer account and credentials, and a personal account and credentials. I am trying to create this under the developer credentials and then enable (long term) users to authenticate themselves. Hence the test users.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info about your use case and with what credentials you plan on authenticating with BAU?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, how about using the service account? When the service account is used, the authorization process for retrieving the code using the browser is not required to be used. I guessed this might be your expected result. But, if this was not included in your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: @esqew Not sure "BAU"? I am trying to pull information from my calendar into python
@Tanaike I had started with that, but then got an error with their quickstart.py having a `ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid redirection after successful Google OAuth2 authorization, and instead fetch the authorization code that you manually paste into the script you can use the special value `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` defined by the OAuth2 specification.

Taking the [calendar quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python) code and modifying it, it can be used something like this:

```
...
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES,
                redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

            auth_uri, _ = flow.authorization_url()
            print(f'Please visit {auth_uri} on your local computer')

            # The user will get an authorization code. This code is used to get the
            # access token.
            code = input('Enter the authorization code: ')
            flow.fetch_token(code=code)

            creds = flow.credentials
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
...
```

**Note** There is more than one way to achieve this: you can create a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview) to be used by the app, and share your calendar with the service app user. You would then access the end user's calendar by using the `calendarId` param.

You should explore the Google API documentation and see what fits you the best.

Comment: Currently digging into the right solution to this problem, but noting for future readers that the proposed answer is here is apparently deprecated: https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html